# image of the map of rational numbers

Tags: ring-theory

Given a map $\phi: {a\over b} \rightarrow \bar{a} \cdot (\bar{b})^{-1} \pmod p$, where $a,b\in\mathbb Z$ and $p$ does not divide $b$ show that $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)= \mathbb Z_p$.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Please spend a bit longer formulating the question. In the current form, there is rather a lot of guesswork needed to make it complete.

Comment: Also making some assumptions, wouldn't the numbers $\frac{1}{1},\frac{2}{1},\ldots,\frac{p}{1}$ map onto $Z_p$. I might be making some bad assumptions about the intent here.

Answer (score 1):

So you're saying let's define $\Bbb{Q} \xrightarrow{\phi} \Bbb{Z}_p$, by taking the reduced $a/b \in \Bbb{Q}$, and mapping it to $a b^{-1} \pmod{p}$.  You want to show that $\phi$ is onto.  That's easily done by letting $b$ be fixed at $1$ and letting $a$ vary over $\Bbb{Z}$.  These are all reduced and so they map as $x \mapsto x \pmod{p}$  which is indeed a surjective homomorphism since the coset $x + p \Bbb{Z}$ is the image of $x$.  We're done.

Let me try to assure some of the commenters that this is correct.  If $a/b = a'/b'$ are two reduced representations for $a/b \neq 0$, then $ab' = a'b$, so that $a \mid a'$ and vice versa, and similarly for $b, b'$, so the two parts of the fractions are equal.  Therefore the above map is well-defined.  Let $\psi : \Bbb{Z} \to \Bbb{Z}_p$ be the canonical hom.  Then all I'm doing is letting $\phi(a/b) = \psi(a)\psi(b)^{-1}$, the inverse always existing since $b \neq 0$ and $\Bbb{Z}_p$ is a field.  Thus the map is definitely well-defined being a composition of a binary operation with a hom.  When I said let $b$ be fixed at $1$, I meant look at the images as $b$ is fixed and $a$ varies.  Since this is a sufficient covering of the range, in order to show that $\phi$ is onto.

**Except** at $0 \in \Bbb{Q}$ define the mapping $\phi(0) = 0$, so that $\phi$ is piecewise defined in the natural way.

Oh, you edited your post.  Your map is not defined for $\gcd(b,p) \neq 1$.  So maybe you want to do this for only prime $p$?  In that case all of my above argument works.

Comment: except that the map is not defined on the entire domain, so it is not a map at all.

Comment: You send $0$ to $0$.  Done

Comment: that was not the problem

Comment: @EnjoysMath Why do we fix b at 1? What about the cases when B=2,3,…, p-1?

Comment: For instance, if we consider $\phi$ (${100}\over{3}$) = ${2}\over{3}$(mod 7) but it is not an integer?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is it what you mean? the image actually is $Q_p$ isn't it? and $Z_p$ is somewhat sub image?

Comment: @Nika Indeed it is not an integer, it is an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p$. EnjoysMath: The problem is that this map is not defined on $\mathbb{Q}$, but on those elements in $\mathbb{Q}$ whose denominators are not divisible by $p$.

Comment: @Nika I have no idea what $\mathbb{Q}_p$ would mean in that context.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I mean by $Q_p$ $\bar{a}$(mod p) $\cdot$ $(\bar{b})^{-1}$ (mod p)

Comment: My math is correct, you probably don't get the notation.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Could you explain what happens to those b which are different from 1?

Comment: No, it is not your notation that is the problem, it is that you have not realized that the map will fail to be defined for any rational whose denominator is divisible by $p$.

Comment: @Nika What you wrote there is not a set.